# Custom view controller container child orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9.2

I have a custom view controller container.

Is there a way to make it respect child view controllers supported interface orientations?

For example we have two view controllers - first supports only portrait, second supports only landscape. Desired behaviour is when I transition from first to second view controller there should be interface rotation triggered somehow(As if second view controller was presented but implemented with view controller containment).

I've implemented a demo https://github.com/seryukov/orientationTest.

In the branch solution1 I have implemented obvious solution using private UIDevice setOrientation: method. Still looking for solution without private API.

Comment: usemethod supportedInterfaceOrientations you could mention the orientation you want. Also if any doubt kindly show some of your code that you have implemented so far.

Comment: @nikhil84 I have implemented a demo: https://github.com/seryukov/orientationTest You can see there that when changing view controllers from portrait to landscape, landscape controller stays portrait until you rotate device and vice-versa. What I want is to force rotate device here.